# How to Filter a Table from lists of Criteria?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to filter Column 7 table in Sheet1 A1:G1000 using Criteria which is on Sheet2 A1:A10

I have written VBA, but it only filter from cell A10 only.

```
Sub FilterTest1()
    Dim c As Variant
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        c = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:A10")
        .Range("A1:G1000").AutoFilter field:=6, Criteria1:=c
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks. but not working.

Comment: Are you looking for including all values from the whole range (`A1:A10`)?

Comment: Thanks,figured I would just use Advance Filter.

Comment: Just figured out though

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for reading,
I just figured how to use Advance Filter.

```
Sub Macro1()

    Range("A1:G1000").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
        Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:A10"), Unique:=False
End Sub
```